# Things required for nice beach experience

Tags: india, beaches, goa-india

I am travelling to [Goa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goa) this October. This is my first time to any beach and I am not sure what should I keep in my bag and back pack to be ready for nice beach experience. My friends told me few suggestions:

1. Beach blanket
2. Slippers which doesn't comes out easily (Image below)

[image]

Is there any other advice related to beach travel? I am also expecting rain/showers during my travel.

Accessories/things I've and I use to carry while travelling: (May assist you while advising me)

- Nikkon 3300 DLSR ([IPX1](http://www.dslrbodies.com/cameras/camera-faq/are-nikon-cameras-okay-to.html) level protection against water)
- OnePlus One SmartPhone (Which doesn't seems to be [water resistant or water proof](https://oneplus.net/support/answer/is-the-oneplus-one-water-resistant-or-waterproof))
- Dell laptop (Not at all water proof)
- leather purse (hard cash, credit/debit cards and govt. id proof)

I would appreciate if you can share any advice regarding Goa also.

Comment: Those are possibly the ugliest slippers I've ever had the displeasure of seeing.

Comment: @MastaBaba I felt the same, but I just got it from somewhere. :)

Comment: I strongly recommend leaving your laptop at home. In fact unless you could organise your group to keep all your belongings under surveillance all time, I wouldn't recommend taking any expensive piece of equipment to the beach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are zillions of items that you can take with you for a nice beach experience. If you are expecting rains then you must take a beach umbrella or a simpler one with you; to keep your phone and other small stuff from getting water and/or moisture keep them in a zip lock sandwich bag.

You can also use this [checklist](http://www.realsimple.com/work-life/travel/travel-planning/beach-vacation-packing-checklist):

- Beach bag
- Glasses and/or contact lenses, if necessary (bring an extra pair,
  too)
- Sunglasses
- Sun hat
- Swimsuit
- Alarm clock
- Batteries for small electronics and cameras
- Beach chairs (if possible)
- Chargers for your cell phone, camera, video camera, and laptop
- Goggles
- Hair dryer
- Antibacterial wipes
- Comb and brush
- Deodorant
- Aid kit, including gas relief tablets, antacid, antidiarrheal
  medicine, antihistamine for allergies, bandages, candied ginger for
  motion sickness, mild laxative, non-aspirin pain reliever,
  thermometer in a hard case
- Insect repellent
- Pack at least one all-purpose sunscreen with SPF 15
- Toothbrush
- Toothpaste
- Books
- Snacks, such as chewy granola bars, dried fruit, mini bagels, nuts,
  and pretzels
- Money (cash, ATM cards, traveler’s checks)
- Travel pillow and blanket
- Maps and directions

Comment: randmcnally is quite American.

Comment: @Arrowfar Thanks for the list. A lot of items though :)